# Infinitest not refreshing in IntelliJ IDEA (15) on gradle project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle, infinitest

The Infinitest plugin under IntelliJ IDEA 15 is not re-running my tests when I change a source file. I wonder if it is because my project is a gradle project. Is there a way to make it refresh automatically?

(It is also Scala code, but I'm using the JUnit test runner, and Infinitest officially supports scala, so I wouldn't think that Scala is the barrier here.)

With a module named "practice", I first added the facet to "practice", changed one of the source files in there, but nothing happened in Infinitest. Tried Ctrl+S, still nothing. Sometimes when I manually recompile the module with Ctrl+F9 then it will refresh.

I also tried adding the facet to "practice_main" and "practice_test" instead of just "practice". I'm not sure which one I'm supposed to add it to in Module Settings.

Comment: It works correctly for me, on a gradle project (Java-only, though), for both source and test code. Do you have any output in the "Logging" tab of the infinitest tool view ?

Comment: @Xavier nothing helpful in the logs. I added more detail in the question.

Comment: Infinitest is monitoring change son compiled classes. So if you want infinitest to trigger on save you need to enable compile on save in the intellij compiler settings.

Comment: @Sebastien Is that Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Make project automatically ?

Comment: This is a known Infinitest issue, for multi-level gradle projects https://github.com/infinitest/infinitest/issues/29

Comment: I have a multi-module gradle project. Thanks for the link.